# Cannot find type 'AnyCancellable' in scope from amplify code snippit

Tags: swift, swiftui, graphql, aws-amplify

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Amplify


class MovesAPI: ObservableObject {
    
    
    @Published var todoLIst: [MoveType?] = [nil]
    
    
    init() {
        listTodos()
    }
    
    func listTodos() -> AnyCancellable { //cannot find type 'AnyCancellable' in scope
        let moveType = MoveType.keys
        let sink = Amplify.API.query(request: .paginatedList(MoveType.self)) //Generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred //Type 'GraphQLRequest<_>' has no member 'paginatedList'
            .resultPublisher
            .sink {
                if case let .failure(error) = $0 {
                    print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
                }
            }
            receiveValue: { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let todos):
                    print("Successfully retrieved list of todos: \(todos)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                }
            }
        return sink
    }

}
```

Ultimately my goal is to fetch all the models of type MoveType from the amplify GraphQL API.
This is a code snippet pasted directly into my project and I'm getting these type errors. any idea why?
From amplify, docs (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/ios#query-by-id) all I did was change the model names to match my backend and remove query params.

Comment: Add 'import Combine' at the top. It's part of the Combine framework.

Answer (score 29):

I think you need:

```
import Combine
```

Comment: That's not in scope for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem of paginatedList code snippet from amplify docs not working as I downloaded Amplify using Cocoapods. When I followed the instructions to download Amplify from Swift Package Manager (SPM) instead at [Amplify iOS Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios) , the paginatedList not working problem is solved. Importing the Combine framework into my Xcode project did not solve the paginatedList problem.

Comment: I tried installing with SPM but still getting the `//Generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred //Type 'GraphQLRequest<_>' has no member 'paginatedList'`

Comment: Did you try relaunching your Xcode project workspace?

Comment: Yes I did but still the same

Answer (score 0):

okay got it working, just had to go way simpler, I switched off using the combined mode

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Amplify


class MovesAPI: ObservableObject {
    
    
    @Published var todoLIst: [MoveType?] = [nil]
    
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func listTodos() {
        print("listing todos")
    
        Amplify.API.query(request: .list(MoveType.self)) { event in
            switch event {
               case .success(let result):
                   switch result {
                   case .success(let todos):
                       print("Successfully retrieved list of todos: \(todos)")
                   case .failure(let error):
                       print("Got failed result with \(error.errorDescription)")
                   }
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("Got failed event with error \(error)")
               }
           }
    
    }

}
```

still, if anyone knows why the code snippets from amplify docs weren't working I would love to know.